# Store paperclip object temporarily in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three field email, phone_number and invoice

user can upload multiple invoice by browse button or drag and drop.

user has two field: email and phone_number
user has_many invoices

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function () {
      // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
      $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '/invoices/upload_file',
        change: function (e, data) {
        },
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.submit();
        }
      });
      // 
      // Load existing files:
  });


</script>
```

Here I am doing whenever user drag and drop file a ajax is fire which and I am doing storing this image object in session but getting

> cant dump error

my controller

```
def new
    session[:invoices_attributes] ||= {}
    @invoice = User.new
    @invoice.invoices.build
end

def upload_file

    session["invoices_attributes"].deep_merge!( user_params["invoices_attributes"].first)
  render nothing: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's impossible to store file data in session. You should try to save it to a temporary file on the filesystem and then store path to the file in session.

You can save temporary file by using

```
# create temporary file
temp_file = TempFile.new('invoice')
# save uploaded file
File.open(temp_file.path, "w") do |f|
  f.write params[:invoices_attributes].delete(:file).read
  f.close
end     

# store temporary file path
params[:invoices_attributes][:file_path] = temp_file.path
```

Code is not tested, but you should get an idea.